# How to get a list of devices connected to an Android device from adb shell

Tags: android, adb, kinect

Can we get the list of devices connected to android device from adb shell.

Comment: [look at the list of adb commands](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) you can list all connected devices by typing devices.

Comment: @Rarw I want the list of devices attached to the android device, not the host PC on which we are running adb

Comment: None of the documentation lists a shell command for that function.

Comment: @SivaPrasadVarma What Android device are you using ? Are you able to use Linaro Linux on that device ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Nexus 10

Comment: Not sure how fast it will be but having a quick look [here](https://wiki.linaro.org/Cycles/1305/Release/Review) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oOhwgDmeXo) sounds doable

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unix based, you should be able to try:

```
ls /dev/tty.*
```

or

```
ls /dev/cu.*
```

Also, I haven't tried myself yet, but the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) 
sounds useful.